# SELECT DISTINCT ON from a subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT user_set, read, last_updated, user_id, pk_id
FROM interaction_log
WHERE user_id = 2002
ORDER BY read, last_updated, user_set
```

The database in use is PostgreSQL (9.1) and the requirement is something like this:

- The ordering of the columns may not change (arrange by read status, then by the last update and then by user_set)
- The 'read' column is an integer which can take a value of only '1' or '0'. last_updated is a positive integer and user_set is a string.
- The user_set column has to be unique. e.g.: if there are 3 entries for a user_set named 'devs' like below:

  1. user_set = "devs" , read = 1, last_updated = 10, user_id = 2002, pk_id = 1
  2. user_set = "devs" , read = 0, last_updated = 30, user_id = 2002, pk_id = 3
  3. user_set = "devs" , read = 0, last_updated = 20, user_id = 2002, pk_id = 2

Then the second entry (with pk_id = 3) should come at the top and none others should show up because it was 'read = 0' and then it's last_updated value was 30 (higher than 20).

SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_set) wants me to have user_set as the first sort order which would change the ordering and hence I cannot do it.

If I do something like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_set) user_set, read, last_updated, thread_id, user_id, id
 FROM message_interaction_log 
    WHERE (user_set, read, last_updated, thread_id, user_id, id) IN
        (SELECT user_set, read, last_updated, thread_id, user_id, id 
            FROM message_interaction_log
            WHERE user_id = 14
            ORDER BY read DESC, last_updated, user_set)
```

Then the 'order by' effect on 'read' is invisible and doing 'read ASC' and 'read DESC' remains the same.

I have tried doing everything I could and I failed every single time. Any help would me much appreciated.

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: I think your post is truncated.

Comment: Rename the column `read`. Don't use **[reserved keywords](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)** as column names.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html It says that 'read' is not reserved and simple queries are working fine anyway! Anyways, I did try changing that, did not work.

Comment: @MillaresRoo Yes, I posted it accidentally (pressed entered on the tag list box). Now I have completed it.

Comment: I guess I will have to re-post this. THis was down-voted and perhaps no one is going to have a look now :( My mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `PARTITION BY` with an OLAP function;

```
SELECT user_set, read, last_updated, user_id, pk_id
FROM (SELECT user_set, read, last_updated, user_id, pk_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY user_set 
                               ORDER BY read ASC, last_updated DESC) as rn
      FROM interaction_log
      WHERE user_id = 2002) data
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY read ASC, last_updated DESC, user_set ASC
```

Essentially, this finds the "top" row per group (`user_set`), and throws out everything else.  For best results, you probably want an index of (`read ASC`, `last_updated DESC`, `user_set` (either direction))